# Хранение данных в памяти с быстрым доступом к ним

Tags: c#, .net, база-данных, хранение-данных

Нужно средствами C# организовать хранение данных в памяти с возможностью быстрого редактирования. Размер данных небольшой, в среднем 1мб, может достигать 100-150мб. Смотрел в сторону баз данных но возможно есть более простое решение этого вопроса. Покажу на примере какие данные нужно размещать:

```
|10.10.10.10|8080|0.287|17|
```

В качестве ключа будет использоваться первое поле (`string`), оно никогда не будет пустым. Нужна возможность выборки по любому из значений.

Comment: Не совсем понятен смысл последнего предложения. Т.е. нужна возможность быстрой выборки по всем полям, кроме первого? Могут ли эти поля иметь повторяющиеся значения или быть пустыми?

Answer (score 3):

Если данные помещаются в память, держите их в памяти.

Заведите структуру, описывающую данные:

```
class Entry
{
    public int IPAddr;
    public int Port;
    public double LoadFactor;
    public int Rank;
}
```

Держите в памяти массив структур (`List<Entry>`). Для быстрого поиска заведите индексы наподобие `Dictionary<int, Entry>` (если ключ уникальный) или `Dictionary<double, List<Entry>>` (если неуникальный). Если данные не меняются в процессе пробега программы, можно, как правильно подсказывает [[@DreamChild](/users/10162/dreamchild)](/users/10162/dreamchild), использовать `Lookup<double, Entry>`.

Ну или отображать не в `Entry`, а в номер элемента в списке.

Не забудьте сериализироваться назад в базу данных при закрытии приложения (или при commit'е).

Comment: если уж ключ не уникален, то лучше использовать **Lookup**

Comment: @DreamChild: Угу, `Lookup` семантичнее. Но он [вроде иммутабельный](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13362570/276994), так что если данные будут меняться, может и не подойти.